# In Angular, how to deal with callback parameter in URL after authentication

Tags: angular

In my Angular app I am using MSAL for Azure AD authentication. So after login it redirect backs to URL we specified. So I specified a URL like this

http://localhost:4200/reply1

So my intention is to stay on that page itself but to do some function based on that reply1 parameter there. So by reply1 I can understand its a redirection after login..

I tried to set my route configuration to specify reply1 also to map to the same component. Honestly I am not sure thats the best approach even though no idea how to understand that reply1??

Also if there is any arguments as well, how can we deal with..

like http://localhost:4200/reply1?i=10

Answer (score -1):

You can pass parameters in any of your routes, it's actually so easy
here's an example: https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-6-url-parameters-860db789db85

Comment: Can't see results. Medium content is behind a paywall.